# Creating new data using POST dosen't work in laravel 5

Tags: php, extjs, laravel-4, laravel-5

I've got a problem moving from laravel 4 to laravel 5.
I hae a test example that i downloadet some time ago in laravel 4 and it works prefectly. But when i wrote the same example it stops at some point.
I'm using ExtJS 5 for framework.

Controller:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\books;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class BookController extends Controller {

    public function load()
    {
        $books = DB::table('books')->select('id','title','author','price','quantity')
                    ->orderBy('id','asc')->get();

        // dodajemo u array polje cijena koja množi cijenu i količinu

        foreach ($books as $b)
            {
                $b->cijena = $b->price * $b->quantity;


            }


        die(print_r($data));
        //die(print_r($books));

        return Response::json($books);

        //print_r($x);
    }

    public function create()
    {

        $input = Input::all();

        if ($input['id'] == '')
        {

            $books = DB::table('books')->insertGetId(array('title' => $input['title'], 'author' => $input['author'], 'price' => $input['price'], 'quantity' => $input['quantity']));

            return Response::json(array('msg'=>'New Books record successfully created.'));
        }
        else
        {
            $book = DB::table('books')->where('id', '=', $input['id']);
            $book -> update($input);
            return Response::json(array('msg' => 'Book successfully update.'));
        }
    }

    public function delete($bookId)
    {   
        //$x = $bookId;
        //die(print_r($x));
        $book = DB::table('books')->where('id', '=', $bookId)->delete();

    }

}
```

Route:

```
<?php

Route::get('load_books', 'BookController@load');
Route::post('create', 'BookController@create');
Route::get('delete/{bookId}', 'BookController@delete');


Route::get ('/', function()
{
    //return View::make('index');
    return View::make('books');
});
```

when i open the aplication in browser i get the view and the form of ExtJS, thanks to @lukasgeiter i addet use DB & use Response and got the data shown.
In ExtJS POST methode is used to create new book

The problem now is when i try to create new book i get:

```
 POST http://localhost/testni_server/artikli/public/books/create 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

And i can't figure out how to fix this problem.
 Evrything is the same as in laravel 4, except it works in laravel 4, but not in laravel 5

Comment: The route is `load_books` and you try to call `books/load_books`

Comment: I did try books/load_books but still the same error

Comment: Do other routes work?

Comment: no, it's the same error .../public/books/create?_dc=1425401949558&page=1&start=0&limit=25 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Please quickly try `/public/index.php/books/create?...`

Comment: i get this NotFoundHttpException in compiled.php line 7671:

Comment: Cheking laravel error log, now i get  Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DB' not found

Comment: You probably have several issues here. One being that you have to add `use DB;` or reference the class with a backslash `\DB::table()`. Also it sounds like your `.htaccess` isn't working. check that you have mod_rewrite enabled and `AllowOverride All`

Comment: I have add use DB and use Response,enabled mod_rewrite and changed AllowOverride to AllowOverride All now load_books works,
but for create i get MethodNotAllowedHttpException in compiled.php line 7695:

Comment: Probably because you're not calling it with POST like you specified in your routes...

Comment: Can you please explain, because i am using POST in ExtJS

Comment: Please add to your question what URL you call (like you did for `load_books`)

Comment: URL for create POST http://localhost/testni_server/artikli/public/books/create 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: And that's `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` in the log?

Comment: Yup, when i create a new book, i get that, and in laravel log i have MethodNotAllowedHttpException for that error

Comment: Are those all your routes?

Comment: Yes, that are all the routes i have.

Comment: Try this: `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: Didn't work, still getting the same error

Comment: Then I really can't help you. I can only tell you that the error comes from trying to access a route with the wrong HTTP method. Good luck figuring it out