# Loading data using GET dosen't work in laravel 4

Tags: php, extjs, laravel-4

I have a test example that i downloaded can you see here
http://www.techzoo.org/web-programming/php-programming/extjs-4-and-laravel-4-crud-tutorial.html,

but not working, I'm using ExtJS 4 and Laravel VERSION = 4.2.17 and I think I have a similar problem to this 
[Creating new data using POST dosen't work in laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28852418/creating-new-data-using-post-dosent-work-in-laravel-5)
but is not my problem, my problem is when i try load books i get:

[blog]: "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/laravel4/app/views/books/load_books?_dc=1428772252288&page=1&start=0&limit=25"

I'm new in Laravel but i've created a new folder for /books/load_books controller but i can't resolve it

Comment: putting this in your browser works http://localhost/laravel4/app/views/books/load_books ? I guess not  ... that's url is simply wrong it doesn't exist and the error is telling you that

Comment: My code of controller and routs  is equals to this Creating new data http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28852418/creating-new-data-using-post-dosent-work-in-laravel-5 but not workink nothing transactions

Comment: Thanks i know, but how or I can solve it? my routes are correct in Laravel this my route Route::get('books/load_books', 'BookController@load');

Comment: I'm really new at Laravel but I have experience in Extjs, and I think the problem is that I put the code Javascript in the folder view